# Splitting a list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to split a list (as if splitting a string by a delimiter), ideally in a functional style, and was surprised how hard it seems to be. Or maybe my code is just unnecessarily complicated?

```
fun <ElemType : Comparable<ElemType>> Iterable<ElemType>.split(delim: ElemType): 
List<List<ElemType>> {
    return this.fold(emptyList<List<ElemType>>()) { 
        acc: List<List<ElemType>>, elem: ElemType ->
        if (elem == delim) 
            acc + listOf(emptyList<ElemType>())
        else if (acc.isEmpty()) 
            listOf<List<ElemType>>(listOf<ElemType>(elem)) 
        else 
            acc.take(acc.size - 1) + listOf(acc.last() + elem)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val l = listOf("1", "", "2", "3", "", "", "4")
    println(l.split(""))
    
    val l2 = listOf(1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4)
    println(l2.split(0))
}
```

The result for both cases is `[[1], [2, 3], [], [4]]`.

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/0PB0UrFsj)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why "ideally in a functionally style"?

Comment: Because I can write procedural code in a lot of languages, but am learning functional idioms in Kotlin.

Comment: Well you chose a tough assignment to learn functional idioms with xD But possibly if you would have handled it list-by-list by searching for the delimiters instead of element-by-element it might have been easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated because you are making it unnecessarily complicated.

I wouldn't use `.fold` to accomplish this.

Think about how many list operations this line does:
`acc.take(acc.size - 1) + listOf(acc.last() + elem)`

- `acc.take(acc.size - 1)` copies the current list of sublists except the last.
- `listOf(acc.last() + elem)` (I believe this could be just `acc.last() + elem`?) creates a new list with one element appended to the last list.

We know that once we've seen a delimiter, we don't need to touch any previous lists, we can just continue looking at what's ahead of us.

This makes it a perfect choice for a `sequence` builder.

```
fun <ElemType> Iterable<ElemType>.split(delim: ElemType): List<List<ElemType>> {
    return sequence {
        val currentList = mutableListOf<ElemType>()
        for (elem in this@split) {
            if (elem == delim) {
                yield(currentList.toList())
                currentList.clear()
            } else {
                currentList.add(elem)
            }
        }
        yield(currentList.toList())
    }.toList()
}
```

Other notes: Your function requires `ElemType` to extend `Comparable<ElemType>`. I do not see any reason for this. You can remove that restriction.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I needed `Comparable` for `elem == delim`, but I now realize that `equals` is defined for all objects.

Comment: And maybe I don't even need the `toList()` at the end ... this could even be lazy.

Comment: @FelixDombek Yup, if possible I would recommend using it as a `Sequence` instead of a `List`